# PowerShell Capture Write-Host output

Tags: powershell

I am having to run a Microsoft cmdlet, and the important bit of information is written to console using a Write-Host line within the cmdlet.

It is NOT returned, so I cannot do $result = Commandlet ...
A different value is returned that is not of use to me, what I actually need is printed to console within the commandlet is there anyway I can 'sniff' or 'scrape' the console to get the information I want?

```
$result = Test-Cluser
```

Test-Cluster will print stuff like: 'HadUnselectedTests', 'ClusterConditionallyApproved', etc.
But the value it returns in the path to the .htm report file.
And the .htm report file does not contain one of those status codes unfortunately so I cannot just parse the .htm file for it either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note: As for **why you should never use [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host) to output *data***, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375).

In **PSv5+**:

```
$result = Test-Cluster 6>&1
```

Since version 5, `Write-Host` writes to the newly introduced information stream, whose number is `6`.

`6>&1` [redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) that stream to the success output stream (number `1`), so that it too can be captured in `$result`.

*Caveat*: The related **[`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host)** cmdlet does *not* write to the information stream; its output ***cannot* be captured** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57328249/45375) for the differences between `Write-Host` and `Out-Host`.

---

In **PSv4-**:

There is ***no* way to capture `Write-Host` output *in-session***.

The only **workaround** is to **launch another instance of Powershell** with the target command specified as a *string*.
**Caveats:**

- Such an invocation is slow,
- prevents passing of arguments with their original data type
- invariably only returns *string* data (lines of text)
- returns output from *all* output streams, including error output

  - for a list of all output streams, see [`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection)

```
$result = powershell -noprofile -command 'Test-Cluster'
```

<sup>Note that using a *script block* to pass the command (`-command { Test-Cluster }`) would *not* work, because PowerShell then uses serialization and deserialization to emulate the in-session behavior.</sup>

---

#### Optional reading: output streams in PowerShell and how to redirect them:

[`Get-Help about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) discusses a list of all output streams, which can be targeted by their *numbers*; since PSv5, these are:

```
1 ... success output stream (implicit output and Write-Output output)
2 ... error output stream (Write-Error and unhandled errors)
3 ... warnings (Write-Warning)
4 ... verbose output (Write-Verbose)
5 ... debug output (Write-Debug)
6 ... (v5+) Write-Information and Write-Host output
```

Note that some streams are silent by default and require opt-in to produce output, either via a preference variable (e.g., `$VerbosePreference`) or a common parameter (e.g., `-Verbose`)

- `{n}>` allows redirecting the number `{n}` stream; if `{n}` is omitted, `1` is implied:

  - to a file (e.g., `3> c:/tmp/warnings.txt`
  - to "nowhere", i.e suppressing the output (e.g., `3> $null`)
  - to the success output stream (e.g., `3>&1`); note: only stream `1` can be targeted this way.
- `*>` targets *all* output streams.

Note: Unlike in POSIX-like shells (e.g., `bash`), the *order* of *multiple* redirection expression does *not* matter.

Therefore, the following POSIX-like shell idiom - which redirects error output to the success stream and silences *only* the *original* success output - does NOT work:

```
... 2>&1 1>$null # !! NO output in PowerShell
```

To achieve this in PowerShell, you mustn't redirect `1` and instead *filter* the objects in the success by their stream of origin.

Case in point: In the end, the OP wanted the following: **capture only warning output**, without the regular (success) output:

```
Test-Cluster 3>&1 | Where-Object { $_ -is [System.Management.Automation.WarningRecord] }
```

Objects that came from the warning stream have type `[System.Management.Automation.WarningRecord]`, which is what enables the filtering above.

Comment: Nice! The PSv5+ part should be documented in [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6)

Comment: `$result = SomeFunction 6>&1` turns newlines into spaces by default. To keep newlines: `$result = SomeFunction 6>&1 | Out-String` or set [preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-6#ofs) before the command to be redirected: `$OFS = "\`n"`

Comment: @zett42: I think you're seeing the behavior of `Write-Host`, not effects of the `6>&1` redirection. When you pass an array to `Write-Host`, it is stringified the way you describe. That `6>&1` isn't to blame can be verified as follows: `function SomeFunction { 1, 2, 3 | Write-Host }; $result = SomeFunction 6>&1` - `$result` will contain each number on its own line.

Comment: @mklement0 Correct! When just writing `$result`, I see the separate lines, while I see the "newlines turned into spaces" only with `Write-Host $result`.

Comment: @pico, I'v added a note re `Out-Host` to the answer. If you have further questions, please create a _new_ question post.

Answer (score 1):

I use *> instead of > to redirect all outputs from console to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Example of redirecting text and a variable to a file:

"The "+$set_groups+"ADGroup set!" | Out-File -FilePath $log_path -Append