# Trying to test code, keep getting "System.____comobject" instead of variable value

Tags: powershell, debugging, write-host

I'm trying to write a small powershell script that does a few things

1) Parses Inbox items in my outlook
2) Searches for a RegEx string
3) Dumps the line that matches the RegEx string into a CSV

I can't get #3 to work. It definitely runs for about 10 minutes, but the resulting csv is empty.

Here's a snippet of what I want it to look for:

> Account Name:       Jbond

I tried just slapping a "Write-Host $variable" in various parts to see what was happening, but all I get is "System.____comobject". I can't find a solution online to just convert this into plain text.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)                                                                                  
$RE = [RegEx]'(?sm)Account Name\s*:\s*(?<AccName>.*?)$.*'

$Data = ForEach ($item in $inbox.items){
    $resultText = $item.item.Value
    Write-Host $resultText
    if ($item.from -like "email@email.org"){
        if ($item.body -match $RE){
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                AccName = $Matches.AccName
            }
        }
    }
}
$Data 
$Data | Export-CSv '.\data.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Use:

```sh
$variable | Out-Host # or: Out-Host InputObject $variable
```

rather than

```sh
Write-Host $variable
```

to get meaningful output formatting.

Background information and debugging tips below.

---

Try a combination of the following approaches:

**Use *interactive* debugging:**

- Use GUI editor [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) to place breakpoints in your code and inspect variable values interactively. (In Windows PowerShell you can also use the ISE, but it is obsolescent.)
- Less conveniently, use the [`*-PSBreakpoint` cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-psbreakpoint) to manage breakpoints that are hit when you run your script in a console (terminal) window. A simple alternative is to add [`Wait-Debugger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-debugger) statements to your script, which, when hit, break unconditionally.

---

**Produce *helpful* debugging output:**

Generally, use [`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug) rather than `Write-Host`, which has two advantages:

- You can leave `Write-Debug` calls in your code for on-demand debugging at any time:

  - They are silent by default, and only produce output on an *opt-in* basis, via (temporarily) setting `$DebugPreference = 'Continue'` beforehand or passing the `-Debug` switch (if your script / function is an advanced one, though note that in *Windows PowerShell* this will present a *prompt* whenever a `Write-Debug` call is hit).
  - You do, however, pay a performance penalty for leaving `Write-Debug` calls in your code.
- Debug output is clearly marked as such, colored and prefixed with `DEBUG:`.

The problem you experienced with `Write-Host` is that a**ll  `Write-*` cmdlets perform simple `.ToString()` stringification of their arguments, which often results in unhelpful representations**, such as `System.____comobject` in your case.

To **get the same rich output formatting you would get in the console**, use the following technique, which uses `Out-String` as a helper command:

```sh
$variable | Out-String | Write-Debug
```

If you want to control the view (list vs. table vs. wide vs. custom) explicitly, insert a `Format-*` call; e.g.:

```sh
$variable | Format-List | Out-String | Write-Debug
```

It is generally only the standard `Out-*` cmdlets that use PowerShell's output formatting system.

---

**A quick-and-dirty alternative to `Write-Debug` is to use [`Out-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-host)** rather than `Write-Host` - e.g., for quick insertion of debugging commands that you'll remove later; `Out-Host` itself **performs the usual output formatting**, which simplifies matters:

```sh
# Default for-display formatting
$variable | Out-Host  # or: Out-Host -InputObject $variable

# Explicit formatting
$variable | Format-List | Out-Host
```

**Caveat**: Aside from formatting, another important difference between `Write-Host` and `Out-Host` is that in PSv5+ only `Write-Host` writes to the host *via the information stream* (stream number `6`), whereas **`Out-Host` truly writes directly to the host, which means that its output cannot be captured** with redirections such as `6>` or `*>` - see [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to capture either `Out-Host` or `$Host.UI.Write()` method, is by capturing the console buffer, like so for example:

```
$Host.UI.Write('aaa')  # or Out-Host 'aaa'
$rect = [System.Management.Automation.Host.Rectangle]::new(0,0,3,1)
$buff = $Host.UI.RawUI.GetBufferContents($rect)
(1..3 | foreach {$buff[0,$_].Character}) -join ''
# The constructor is: [Rectangle]::new(Left,Top,Right,Bottom)
```